# How do i destructure an object

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

i have a function

```
const displayUserPhotoAndName = (data) => {
  if (!data) return;

  // add your code here

  clearNotice();

};
```

After the first if(!data) return; statement that terminates the function if the expected data parameter is not provided, create a statement that de-structures the data parameter and obtains the results property from it;

Create a second statement in the next line that de-structures the results variable you just created, and obtain the first item from it (it is an Array! See https://randomuser.me/api/). Your de-structured array item should be declared as profile. This represents the profile data for the user gotten from the API call that you want to display in your app.

```
const displayUserPhotoAndName = (data) => {
    if(!data) return;    

    // add your code here
    const {results: results} = data;
    const {profile: results} = results;
```

this is where i am right now but i still get an error message saying "you have not destructured the profile property from results obtained from data passed to displayUserPhotoAndName function. your assistance will be very much appreciated...

Comment: This doesn't look right. Have you checked out the documentation for [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as following if you need nth element from results array use

```
{ results: { n: profile } } = data;
```

```js
let data = { results: [1, 2, 3, 4] }

let { results: { 0: profile1, 2: profile2 } } = data;

console.log(profile1)
console.log(profile2)
```

Even you can do further destructuring

```js
let data = { results: [{ name: 'myname1', gender: 'male' }, { name: 'myname2', gender: 'male' }, { name: 'myname3', gender: 'female' }, { name: 'myname4', gender: 'male' }] }

let { results: { 0: profile1, 2: { name, gender } } } = data;

console.log(profile1)
console.log(name)
console.log(gender)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this two ways:

1. Your approach of two steps:

   ```
   const {results} = data;
   const {profile} = results;
   ```
2. Or in one step:

   ```
   const {results: {profile}} = data;
   ```

For a better understanding you should check out [the documentation of object destructuring.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Comment: thanks very much it helped but i think there is a problem because the code isnt running... i'll still be working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example:

```js
const data = {
    results: {
        name: "test1",
        surname: "123"
    },
    profile: {
        name: "test2",
        surname: "321"
    }
};

const { results, profile } = data;

console.log(results);
console.log("====");
console.log(profile);
```